# Add textbox value to single record: syntax error in INSERT INTO statement

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have this error in my Access DB.
Assuming I have a form called ComboAreaProgetto which has one *textbox* called textboxArea and one *button* named AddButton. The button has an event procedure on the *click* event which must add the textbox content into the field 'Area progetto' of the table ComboAreaProgetto. Here is the following code:

```
Private Sub AddButton_Click()
Dim strSQL As String
Dim RnDdB As Database
Set RnDdB = CurrentDb

   RnDdB.Execute " INSERT INTO ComboAreaProgetto (Area Progetto) VALUES ( " & Forms!ComboAreaProgetto!TextBoxArea & ");"

End Sub
```

It gives me syntax error on INSERT INTO statement. I tried to put a different textbox name (an invented one) with this code:

```
Private Sub AddButton_Click()
Dim strSQL As String
Dim RnDdB As Database
Set RnDdB = CurrentDb

   RnDdB.Execute " INSERT INTO ComboAreaProgetto (Area Progetto) VALUES ( " & Me.TextBox123 & ");"

End Sub
```

and it gives me textbox not found instead of INSERT INTO statement error. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use field names with spaces or special symbols, enclose them in square brackets. And if this field has `Text` data type, enclose data in quotes:

```
RnDdB.Execute "INSERT INTO ComboAreaProgetto ([Area Progetto]) VALUES ( '" & Forms!ComboAreaProgetto!TextBoxArea & "');"
```